# How to drag and drop a element to pre selected div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've got the following element draggable enabled.

```
$('.item').draggable({
    revert : true
});
```

What I want is to drag this onto a pre selected div in the document, which also has and effect when clicked.

```
jQuery(".bill-description").click(function()
{
    jQuery(this).next(".bill-item-list").slideToggle(700);
});
```

How can I make this element ( when expanded ) accept a dragging element. What I really want is to know how to handle the event where the `bill-description` div element is open or not.

is there any good way to handle this event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up "droppable" on .bill-description.

```
jQuery(".bill-description").droppable({
    accept: ".item",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

You can learn more about droppable targets here, in the jQuery UI docs:  http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#default

Comment: yes I need the droppable on the element! but, the thing is, the element I need to accept should be expanded! how can I check whether the .bill-description is expanded or not!

Comment: You can always check the size or visibility of the element to determine if it's expanded or not.